# c# Get array index id

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Not sure if am on the right track but I want to find a index id of an array and check if it's equal to another id then display a message. it not working for some reason.

```
int  _findID = 1;       
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("textfile.txt"))
    {
    string line = reader.ReadLine();
    while (line != null)
    {
        string[] array = {line};
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] == findID)
            {
                MesssageBox.show("Line found!!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: please post text file or at least part of it

Comment: Your array will always contain just one element. And you're trying to compare strings to ints. What is it you're *really* trying to accomplish?

Comment: Does this compile ? from where did `findID` come ?

Comment: Shouldn't your one line utilize String.Split()?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx to look like string[] array = line.Split(',');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
if(int.Parse(array[i]) == findID)
```

instead of

```
if (array[i] == findID)
```

You have to convert your `string` representation of your number to a `int` and then compare both `int`'s.

this is even shorter than iterating over an array which always has 1 element:

```
while (line != null) {
    if(int.Parse(array[i]) == findID)
        MesssageBox.Show("Line found!!")
}
```

### EDIT

Try

```
int  _findID = 1;
List<String> names = new List<string>()
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("textfile.txt"))
{
    string line = reader.ReadLine();
    int lineCount = 0;
    while (line != null)
    {
        lineCount++;
        names.Add(line);
        if (lineCount == _findID)
            MessageBox.Show("Line found!!");           
    }
}
```

Comment: it does seem to convert, keep getting error saying "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: @user1285872: How does a line of your file look like?

Comment: the file of text container name.
E.g. 

Mike,
Jason,
Fred,
Kane

all underneath each other

Comment: @user1285872: I don't quite get it. Your file content is a list of names? Where are the numbers you want to compare `findID` with?

Comment: I wanna store each name in an array, then compare the index of each  array (e.g. [0] or [1]) to the findID

Answer (score 0):

@user1285872:  array.Length this will give array length 1 in your case when you check  if (array[i] == findID) thi will be  (0==findID) if the value of findID ==0 then message will show.

Comment: who is comparing `Length` ? `array[i]` ain't length here at all

Answer (score 0):

Your code has various problems:

First if the file is not empty you have an endless loop as you read the line once and always check the same line:

```
string line = reader.ReadLine();
while (line != null) {}
```

The array is always 1 item long as you create it in the loop itself.

But for the problem with the lineID, what exactly is the content of such a line?